# CarrierWave file not saving in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, carrierwave, production-environment

I'm using Rails 4.2.6 and CarrierWave 1.0.0. I have an uploader setup like so:

```
class LetterUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    storage :file
    def store_dir
        "#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/#{model.id}"
    end
end
```

In development, the file saves just fine, in /public/uploads/etc..., but in production, it's not saving. It is getting cached, there is a file in the /tmp directory, but not actually being saved. I've looked all over for a solution, and I can't seem to find one. My intuition was that it was a folder permission issue in my production server, but I made sure that the public folder recursively belonged to my user name, and that didn't help. I even set permissions to 777, to no avail. I can provide more info (on the controller, or anything else) on request, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does your `log/production.log` file show anything? And does the folder `uploads` exists in public?

Comment: The folder does exist in public. I have a helper method that passes the letter to an api. What the production log shows is that I'm getting an error from the api that I'm passing the file to, because it's not actually being passed a file (since the file isn't saving).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't with CarrierWave, but with the fact that an uploaded file doesn't store until the model it is attached to is saved. I re-factored so that the model saves, sends the file to the other api, and then updates the original model, and it works!